# Debugging custom database queries

Tags: database

Is there a convenient way to ask a particular database object to print its query?

Every now and then, I write a DBTNG db_op() in a module, and far to often, I don't quite get the queries right.

I know that devel can output the query log, but that's *all* queries, which, in this type of situation, is a problem more often than not.

I want to do

```
$result = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n')->execute();
dpm($result->queryWithParameters);
dpm($result->finalQuery);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a [`dpq()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpq/7) function in the devel module which seems to fulfill this need.

> Print a SQL string from a DBTNG Query object. Includes quoted arguments.

Comment: I'd give this +100 if I could, never seen that function before

Comment: You could have had, if you offered a bounty. `;)`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but hopefully this answer might be useful to other people: basically Drupal core has its own [DatabaseLog class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!log.inc/class/DatabaseLog/7). You could use it in cases where you don't have Devel module available (like maybe production debugging of slow queries?):

```
Database::startLog('my_custom_key');
// do some SQL operations here...
// print the queries
print_r(Database::getLog('my_custom_key'));
```